# Can I create a calculated metric where I divide a metric by a dimension?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Let's imagine I have an Adobe Analytics hit with an evar10 value of '10000' that doesn't change. This number represents the number of emails that were sent out with this campaign.

I am also counting email opens, or the number of times an image tag was fired. This ends up being a 'visits' count.

Is there any way, *fully within the Adobe interface*, to get to visits/evar10? This is essentially a calculated metric, but because one of the components is technically a dimension, it doesn't work.

Comment: "fully within the Adobe interface" - Best I can think of is to create a Processing Rule to push eVar10 value to an event (set eventX to custom value eVar10) and then use the event in your calculated metric.

Comment: You wrote: "_...evar10 value of '10000' that doesn't change..._" If evar10 does not change, why don't you directly create the Calculated Metric as Visits / 10000 ?